# Hacking Log4j to send custom SysLog messages

Tags: java, log4j

I am making a utility that works directly with syslog data.  It currently uses log4j to write information to the console.  I need some mechanism to send syslog data of a predefined format to another machine.  This data is NOT a log of how the current utility is operating..it is still that logged to stdout for other purposes.

I noticed the `SyslogAppender` and it looks promising.  I would prefer to directly control over log4j, not use the log4j.properties file.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can add an appender to the logger in log4j.

Something like:

```
Logger root = Logger.getRootLogger();

SyslogAppender syslogAppender = new SyslogAppender();
syslogAppender.setSyslogHost(<host ip:port>);
syslogAppender.setThreshold(<required Level>);
syslogAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout(<required pattern>));

root.addAppender(syslogAppender);
```

There are a few more options for the SyslogAppender, see the javadocs for details.

(my first answer on StackOverflow, be gentle! :))